# Jquery Appended Button Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with Jquery/javascript/html. I am trying to display a button inside of  tags in my table. I am appending the information into/onto a section on my html page. Code is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p id="report_area"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file below

```
$('#report_area').append('<table>'); 
$('#report_area').append('<tr>'); 
$('#report_area').append('<th>' + view + '</th><th>' + col_1 + '</th><th>' + col_2 + '</th><th>' + col_3 + '</th>');

$('#report_area').append('</tr>');
var btn=$('<button/>');
btn.text('View');
btn.val=item.SURVEY_JOB_ID;
btn.id=item.SURVEY_JOB_ID;

// recently added code - start
btn.click(function()
    {
      window.localStorage.setItem("MyFirstItem", 10);
      window.location = 'GoToThisOtherPage.htm'
    }
// recently added code - end
$('#report_area').append('<tr><td>'+ btn +'</td><td>' + item.JOB_NUMBER + 
'</td><td>' + item.TITLE + '</td><td>' + item.MODIFICATION_NUMBER + '</td></tr>');
$('#report_area').append('</table>');
```

THis seems to work correctly however, the button is not showing up correctly. It shows up as an object. All the other data displays correctlyMy table row is displayed as :

[object Object]  12   New Job Title  0

[object Object}  30   Title Help Me  1

I'm not sure why it is displaying as [object Object]. When I do something as simple as:

```
$('#report_area').append(btn);
```

the button shows up on the page correctly. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the jquery is wrong in a lot of places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand why this does not work, you have to look at the documentation for [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

> Type: htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery

`append` is able to except any of those types, and handle each of them differently, so when you pass it an element (actually jQuery collection), it is able to intelligently convert it into the desired html.

However, in your case, you are passing it a string, so it will naively treat the string as html.  The reason that this produces `[object Object]`, is because it is relying on native JavaScript to convert the element into a string.  You'll produce the same output with `console.log(btn)`.

```
// append recieves a jQuery collection, calls appropriate methods to obtain html
$('#report_area').append(btn);
// append receives a string, blindly assumes that it is already the desired html
$('#report_area').append(btn + '');
```

#### <s>Solution 1 - Append separately</s>

From your comments on other answers, it doesn't seem like this solution works. I think this is because `append` will automatically add the close tags for the `tr` and `td` when appending, causing the button to be added afterwards.  You could check if this was the case by looking at the html produced in the developer tools of your browser.

```
$('#report_area').append('<tr><td>', [btn, '</tr></td>'])
```

#### Solution 2 - Convert to string properly

```
$('#report_area').append('<tr><td>'+ btn[0].outerHTML +'</td><td>')
```

#### Solution 3 - Constructing everything as jQuery collections

I think the main problem you have been having is to do with mixing elements and strings.  I've written a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L7kLjej/1/) solution that constructs everything as `jQuery` collections.

```
var table = $('<table>');

var btnRow = $('<tr>');

var btnCell = $('<td>');

var btn=$('<button>');
btn.text('View');
btn.val('val');
btn.attr('id', 'id');

btn.on('click', function()
    {
      window.alert('Click');
    });

btnCell.append(btn);
btnRow.append(btnCell);

table.append(btnRow); 
btnRow.append('<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>');

$('#report_area').append(table);
```

Comment: Yea this will require more reading/research. I figured this to be pretty simple (minus the fact that I didn't really know my button was being somewhat stringified), but its given me a headache for today. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you try my other solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried converrting it properly to html as suggested, however, now when I click the button. Nothing happens. Before, it would navigate the user to another page. Let me see if I can edit my  original post to show the onClick functionality of my button. Oh, but yes, this does make it look like an actual button on the page now.

Comment: Eureka! (Spell Check)....but the last solution works properly. My buttons are clickable now and displaying correctly. Information is being passed via the buttons and I am being navigated to the next page. Thanks so much for your time and effort. The only thing left for me to do is to add a table header and possibly some table formatting. I believe from your help I should be able to take it from here lol. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is converting `btn` to a string because you're concatenating several strings to it.

It should work if you do this.

```
$('#report_area').append('<tr><td>');
$('#report_area').append(btn);
$('#report_area').append('</td><td>' + item.JOB_NUMBER + 
'</td><td>' + item.TITLE + '</td><td>' + item.MODIFICATION_NUMBER + '</td></tr>');
$('#report_area').append('</table>');
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I am able to get the button to display properly, however, the button appears first, then on the line below it, the rest of my information is displayed in a single line. The button is not on the same line as the rest of my info.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to set native DOM properties on a jQuery object. Remember, a jQuery object is a superset of a native DOM object. Alter your code to use the `.val()` and `.attr()` jQuery methods like so:

```
var btn=$('<button/>');
btn.text('View');
btn.val(item.SURVEY_JOB_ID);
btn.attr('id', item.SURVEY_JOB_ID);
```

Alternately, you can chain these methods together for convenience:

```
var btn= $('<button/>')
    .text('View')
    .attr('id', item.SURVEY_JOB_ID)
    .val(item.SURVEY_JOB_ID);
```

Finally, alter your use of the `.append()` method to append the content like so:

```
$('#report_area').append(
    '<tr><td>',
    [
        btn,
        '</td><td>' + item.JOB_NUMBER + '</td><td>' + item.TITLE + '</td><td>' + item.MODIFICATION_NUMBER + '</td></tr></table>'
    ]);
```

Comment: I also tried your suggestion. This does get the button to display correctly, but again, it places the button on top and the rest of the information under it in a single line. Not too sure why its doing this. There are now breaks and they are in the correct tags.